# eigenvalue decomposition using matlab

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matlab

I would like to diagnolize a rank-1 matrix using the well known eigenvalue decomposition as
$\mathbf{U}^H\mathbf{A}\mathbf{U} = diag (M, 0,\cdots, 0)$, where $\mathbf{A}$ is a Hermitian matrix and $\mathbf{U}$ is a unitary matrix.

While if we use eig.m in matlab, the resulting $\mathbf{U}$ fails to satisfy the property of unitary matrix $\mathbf{U}^H\mathbf{U} = \mathbf{I}_{M}$ due to the unit round-off error and the use of \pi.

What should I do?

The code can be given:

```
    clc
    clear all
    close all

    c           = 340;
    j           = sqrt(-1);
    theta_s     = 0;
    theta_s     = theta_s*pi/180;

    M           = 6;
    delta       = 0.012;
    M_vector    = (0:M-1)';
    theta       = 0:0.1:360;
    theta       = theta*pi/180;

    f           = 4000;

    %% eigenvalue decomposition of matrix 
    omega       = 2*pi*f;
    d           = exp(-j*omega*M_vector*delta/c);
    h_DS        = 1/M*d;
    A           = d*d';

    [U,D]       = eig(A);
```

Comment: Use of $\pi$??? ${}$

Comment: The entries in matrix $\mathbf{A}$ relate to $\pi$, and the $pi$ in matlab is an approximate value.

Comment: Does it badly fail to satisfy it, or is it satisfying up to double-precision round-off?

Comment: Badly failed. I can give a test code

Comment: Will your $\bf A$ always have some special property for your purposes (e.g. be symmetric or Hermitian)?

Comment: The matrix A is a Hermitian matrix.

Comment: Possibly worth looking at: https://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/337468-how-to-get-orthogonal-eigenvectors-for-degenerate-normal-matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to round-off errors, MATLAB isn't recognizing that your matrix is Hermitian.  You can fix this easily by averaging A with its Hermitian transpose:

```
>> ishermitian(A)

ans =

  logical

   0

>> B=(A+A')/2;
>> ishermitian(B)

ans =

  logical

   1
```

Once you've done this, U'*U=I as expected.

```
>> [U,D]=eig(B);
>> U'*U

ans =

  Columns 1 through 4

   1.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 - 0.0000i
  -0.0000 - 0.0000i   1.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 - 0.0000i  -0.0000 - 0.0000i
   0.0000 - 0.0000i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i   1.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 - 0.0000i
  -0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   1.0000 + 0.0000i
   0.0000 - 0.0000i   0.0000 - 0.0000i   0.0000 - 0.0000i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i
  -0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 - 0.0000i   0.0000 - 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i

  Columns 5 through 6

   0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 - 0.0000i
   0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i
   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i
  -0.0000 - 0.0000i   0.0000 - 0.0000i
   1.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i
   0.0000 - 0.0000i   1.0000 + 0.0000i
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Thank you!!!